# Getting a null pointer exception when trying to pass a boolean via an interface

Tags: android, nullpointerexception

I am using an interface, as is standard (best?) practice to communicate between a series of fragments. The business logic requires the app to collect some information in fragment n+1 and if the "next" button is tapped then the user goes to fragment n+2. If the "back" button is tapped then the user goes to fragment n. I am also using a nice sliding animation to display the transition from one fragment to the other depending on the direction. I cannot figure out why this is not working and I am getting the null pointer error on this line:
         createPlanListener.onCreatePlan(bundle);

Here is the initial fragment **Mealplan.class** where I trigger the transition. I have left all of the boiler plate code generated by Android Studio as is:

```
public class MealplanFragment extends Fragment {
    private static final String ARG_PARAM1 = "param1";
    private static final String ARG_PARAM2 = "param2";

    private String mParam1;
    private String mParam2;

    private FloatingActionButton createMealplan;
    // bunch of variables
    private Bundle bundle;

    private OnCreatePlanListener createPlanListener;

    public MealplanFragment() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }

    public static MealplanFragment newInstance(String param1, String param2) {
        MealplanFragment fragment = new MealplanFragment();
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putString(ARG_PARAM1, param1);
        args.putString(ARG_PARAM2, param2);
        fragment.setArguments(args);
        return fragment;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        if (getArguments() != null) {
            mParam1 = getArguments().getString(ARG_PARAM1);
            mParam2 = getArguments().getString(ARG_PARAM2);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Other code that has nothing to do with the bundle or the listener


        // Floating action bar
        createMealplan.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                bundle.putBoolean("direction", true);
                createPlanListener.onCreatePlan(bundle);
            }
        });

        return mealplanView;
    }

    public void onButtonPressed(Bundle bundle) {
        if (createPlanListener != null) {
            createPlanListener.onCreatePlan(bundle);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onAttach(Context context) {
        super.onAttach(context);
        mealplanContext = context;
        if (context instanceof OnCreatePlanListener) {
            createPlanListener = (OnCreatePlanListener) context;
        } else {
            throw new RuntimeException(context.toString()
                    + " must implement OnFragmentInteractionListener");
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onDetach() {
        super.onDetach();
        createPlanListener = null;
    }

    public interface OnCreatePlanListener {
        void onCreatePlan(Bundle bundle);
    }

    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
    }
```

And here is **MainActivity.class**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements
        MealplanFragment.OnCreatePlanListener {

   // Non related variables


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

       // MealplanFragment is the default fragment at onCreate
        if (savedInstanceState == null) {
            getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.frame_container, new MealplanFragment(), null).commit();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreatePlan(Bundle bundle) {
        if (bundle != null) {
            Boolean direction = bundle.getBoolean("direction");
            ReceptionFragment fragment = new ReceptionFragment();
            openFragment(bundle, fragment, direction);
        }
    }


    private void openFragment(Bundle bundle, Fragment fragment, Boolean direction) {

        fragment.setArguments(bundle);

        //Starting fragment with animation
        if (direction) {
            android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().setCustomAnimations(R.anim.enter_from_right, R.anim.exit_to_right, R.anim.enter_from_right, R.anim.exit_to_right).replace(R.id.frame_container, fragment, null);
            fragmentTransaction.commit();
        } else {
            android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().setCustomAnimations(R.anim.enter_from_left, R.anim.exit_to_left, R.anim.enter_from_left, R.anim.exit_to_left).replace(R.id.frame_container, fragment, null);
            fragmentTransaction.commit();
        }
    }



}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
createMealplan.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            bundle.putBoolean("direction", true);
            createPlanListener.onCreatePlan(bundle);
        }
    });
```

This is your click listener. `bundle` is defined as class variable but never initialized and hence the null pointer exception. I would suggest that you use a local variable -> create a new instance of bundle, add data and then invoke callback. Also, `createPlanListener` is nullable, so you should add a check for that as well.

Comment: Is this method: public void onButtonPressed(Bundle bundle)  not sufficient to check if the listener is nullable?

Comment: 1. In your snippet, `onButtonPressed()` is never used so I am not sure.
2. `bundle` is null and hence the null pointer exception. You need to initialize it.